# how to implement a tree where the branches have a value

Tags: c++, tree

is there a way the connection between two nodes (the branch lets say) can contain a value?

The use of this being maybe there is a cost variable and to traverse from one node to the root the program would have to find the most cost effective route.

[image: illustrated as shown]
illustrated as shown

Comment: Sadly your question can be answered with garbage like, "Put the right characters in the right order and compile." You don't want that. You can salvage this question by tightening the question up to restrict the range of possible answers. A good way to do this is to attach your best attempt at solving the problem and ask questions about it.

Comment: That said, consider connecting the nodes with an `edge` structure that tracks the weights.

Comment: It's a weighted graph. Store the cost along with the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly common in graph problems. Typically you create a class named `Edge` (or possibly `Arc`, or some people just call them `lines`) that contains the association between two nodes, and the weight of that Edge/Arc/Line.

```
// Warning: this is really pseudo-code.

class Node;

class Edge {
    unsigned weight;
    Node *node;
};

class Node {    // Also often called a Vertex
    std::vector<Edge> edges;
    // ...
};

// find minimum cost path from start to end in a DAG:
unsigned find_path(Node &start, Node &end) { 
    unsigned current_weight = -1;

    for (auto const &e : start.edges) {
        if (e == end)
            return e.weight;
        weight = e.weight + find_path(*(e.node))
        if (weight < current_weight)
            current_weight = weight;
    return current_weight;
}
```

Note that this is a just the most obvious brute-force DFS traversal algorithm, so it's not practical for large graphs or anything like that. Should be enough to impart the general idea though.

Of course, there's a lot more that can be added here. This is just the briefest sketch, to give at least a starting point of a direction you can go.